# Triggers in users

Tags: trigger

Account Object:
               I have Created a One Custom Field called Admin user with the Datatype as Checkbox,I want a Trigger code whenever the other user(Not Included Admin user) create any record in Account object,the Custom Checkbox field is Marked as Checked,if Admin user Create any Record in Account object,the Checkbox field not Checked ,I want a trigger for Creating a New Record or Inserting the ecord the Operation Should be in Process,Anyone Guide ME for the Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code may help to your scenario. This code support all admin profile users. If your checkbox default value is false this code is working fine.

```
trigger AdminUserCheck on Account (Before Insert) {

    if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isBefore) {

        Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();    // Initialize Set of User Id
        Map<Id,String> userIdAndProfileNameMap = new Map<Id,String>();    // Initialize userId and  profile name map

        for(Account acc : trigger.new) {
            userIds.add(acc.CreatedById);    // Add user Id
        }

        if(userIds.size() > 0) {
            for(User usr : [SELECT Id,Name,Profile.Name FROM User WHERE Id IN :userIds]) {    //Query User and its profile Name
                if(usr.Profile.Name != null) {
                    userIdAndProfileNameMap.put(usr.Id, usr.Profile.Name);    // put map values
                }
            }
        }    

        for(Account acc1 : trigger.new) {
            if(userIdAndProfileNameMap.containsKey(acc1.CreatedById) {
                if(!userIdAndProfileNameMap.get(acc1.CreatedById) == 'Admin') { //Check the user admin or not
                    acc1.Admin_User__c = TRUE;  
                }  
            } 
        }
    }
}
```